# Mongoose not connecting via IPv6

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ipv6, ipv4

When running a replica set I need to add { "family: 4" } to my mongoose.connect line in order for the connection to work. When just running one Mongo instance there is no problem (then I can run it on both IPv4 and 6). Im guessing I need to reconfig my replica set, but how?